# Automatic transmission trouble

Tags: automatic-transmission, mercedes-benz

I have a Mercedes A-180 with automatic transmission, which has recently started jerking at gear changes, especially the lowest gears - but it isn't always. About half the time it works smoothly for a whole journey, other times it start jumping either from the start or after driving a while.

I took it to a garage and was told that this is definitely the solenoids and it will cost about £3000 to recondition; I'm somewhat skeptical about that - they are not specialists in gearboxes of any type and hadn't performed anything more than the most basic examination. It doesn't seem to be related to temperature, but it's hard to tell in UK, since the weather has been relatively warm for a long time.

So, am I looking at something that is likely to cost that much? I know it isn't much to go on, but make a reasonable guess.

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level using the dipstick? I'd start there.

Comment: @GdD I haven't - I wouldn't know where to find it; according to the mechanic there isn't one. Maybe he doesn't know.

Comment: How to check is in your owners manual, I'm pretty sure it has one.  Even if there isn't one there's a way to check underneath the car, if the mechanic says there's no way to look then they either don't know what they are talking about or are full of BS. Take it to a reputable transmission shop instead.

Comment: @GdD Good advice in any circumstances, thank you

Comment: @GdD - Mercs just don't have dipsticks, just the holes where they will go; they're sealed. Explanation added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check is the transmission oil level. This isn't as simple as most engines. Most Mercs don't come with dipsticks, neither for the engine nor transmission.
You have to buy them separately - they're considered 'service tools' [ie you must remove them after checking & renew the break-away seal] & it's quite a faff to measure the levels (about 10 steps, you can't just wipe it & dunk it). If, after checking & topping up as appropriate, behaviour is the same, then I'd take it to a proper auto transmission specialist or at least 'grey' Merc specialist rather than trust your nearest 'plugs & filters' guy. If he thinks there's no dipstick so it can't be done, then don't trust him as far as you can spit him.

See https://www.mercedesmedic.com/how-to-check-automatic-tranmission-fluid-level-in-mercedes-benz/ for a clear pictorial DIY approach to measuring the fluid levels yourself.
Parts:
Dipsticks are about $£€ 10 [eBay, UK](https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/mercedes-transmission-dipstick/bn_7024967223?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=710-53481-19255-0&campid=5337487966&customid=&toolid=10001)
Example break-off seal replacement $20 [Amazon US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K0UCY5E)
Always double-check specific model/year compliance. These things are almost, but not quite, universal.